# want a common DataBase for Unity Game and a Website

Tags: web-services, asmx, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity 5 where i need to load description and items from a database which gets updated when we enter values in a website. 
I need to know some way to consume asmx webservices in unity 5.

Can somebody tell me in detail How can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about Unity. I have only tinkered with the game engine. So the only advice I can offer is, try posting your question on this site https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ (if you haven't already). It's the same thing as SO just for game development specifically. Good luck in your endeavors.